# How to create/outsource app sharer that will either redirect too app or to web view

Tags: php, share, deep-linking

We have an iOS and Android mobile app, and we are changing the current sharer functionality.

**Current functionality**

1. A link is shared through the app, which goes to sharer.baseurl.com/sharer/xxx/yyy, xxx and yyy being different pages and id's, for example, profile/1.
2. When the link is opened the page sharer enters, and it automatically redirects to our onelink.to, which either opens the app stores or falls back to the base url.

This is fine, but we want to implement the web view, for users who don't have the app downloaded, so the goal is to take xxx/yyy and open that same page on the website.

The problem with onelink is that it doesn't allow to go to a specific page after the fallback, only base URL.

**Expected behaviour**

1. Link is shared.
2. Link is opened. First we check if the app is installed.
3. If app is installed: Open it or open market page.
4. If app is NOT installed: Go to web view for that specific shared content.

What we are trying to achieve is something like TikTok. If you don't have the app, you will se the specific content in web mode, and then we will prompt you to install the app.

**Our tech stack**

We use a server based on PHP. The website is also on the server, so it is the same code all in one. The views are already built and working, so all I need is to be able to redirect.

Has someone done something similar or knows a tool that could serve that purpose?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register `Android App Links` (Android) and `Universal Links` (iOS) with your app. These links will use default URL scheme and open your app if it is installed or the web browser if it isn't. This is handled by the OS, so no need for external tools / services.

[Android](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links) / [iOS](https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/)

Comment: I ended doing exactly that, thanks for posting the answer anyways. Marked as correct.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!